# How to use shared data across iterations of processes using multiprocessing in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm fairly new to python and definitely new to multiprocessing in Python. I'm looking to create a shuffle distribution across two matrices using multiprocessing and I've gotten stuck, because what I'm writing loads the data from the hard drive over and over instead of loading the data once and transferring it to the workers. I don't understand why the code above the `if __name__="__main__"` gets called over and over again, but when I move the code within that block the processes just hang. I'm also sure there is some more graceful way of passing the jobs to the pool than having a function that takes in the index since no input is really needed other than the matrices.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
import scipy.io
from multiprocessing import Pool
from comparisons import D
import time

nshuff = 1000

print('Loading data...')
mat = scipy.io.loadmat(PATH_TO_DATA)
A = mat["A"]
B = mat["B"]

[nbin,ndata,nday] = A.shape
def d_shuff(A,B):
    rng = default_rng()
    C = B[:,rng.permutation(ndata),:]
    out = np.empty((nday,nday,ndata))
    out[:] = np.nan
    for i in range(ndata):
        out[:,:,i] = D((A[:,i,:],C[:,i,:]))
    return out

def d_shuff_(i):
    return d_shuff(A,B)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool() as pool:
        t = time.time()
        async_result = pool.map_async(d_shuff_, range(nshuff))
        out = async_result.get()
        print(time.time()-t)
        print('Saving output...')
        scipy.io.savemat(
            PATH_TO_OUTPUT,
            {"out":out}
            )
```

Comment: "Multithreading" is *not* a synonym of "multiprocessing."

Answer (score 0):

To pass to each worker the two matrices `A` and `B` you can use the function `Pool.starmap`.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
import scipy.io
from multiprocessing import Pool
from comparisons import D
import time

def d_shuff(A,B):
    rng = default_rng()
    [nbin,ndata,nday] = A.shape
    C = B[:,rng.permutation(ndata),:]
    out = np.empty((nday,nday,ndata))
    out[:] = np.nan
    for i in range(ndata):
        out[:,:,i] = D((A[:,i,:],C[:,i,:]))
    return out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nshuff = 1000

    print('Loading data...')
    mat = scipy.io.loadmat(PATH_TO_DATA)
    A = mat["A"]
    B = mat["B"]

    with Pool() as pool:
        t = time.time()
        workers_args = [(A, B) for i in range(nshuff)]
        async_result = pool.starmap(d_shuff, workers_args)
        out = async_result.get()
        print(time.time()-t)
        print('Saving output...')
        scipy.io.savemat(
            PATH_TO_OUTPUT,
            {"out":out}
            )
```

For clarification, when you use multiprocessing you will need to copy the matrices to all the processes. This is because every new process that you start will have its own memory space.

If you use multithreading instead you could load the matrices A and B once and then access them from every thread since every thread shares the same memory space (but beware the python Global Interpreter Lock).

Comment: The goal is to run the same function over and over again, generating a random permutation of the matrix B and then running the function D across all the pairs of datapoints between A and B. I'd like to run the Pool over the shuffles instead of the datapoints because the number of shuffles is typically much larger than the number of datapoints.

Comment: Try to pass the matrices using the starmap function and bring the code to load the input into the `if __name__ == '__main__'` .